# ng2 google chart not showing tooltip when hovering on chart legend

Tags: angular, ng2-google-chart

I am using ng2 Google Chart, and I am currently facing an issue. When I hover over the chart legend, it doesn't show the tooltip. However, when I hover inside the chart, the tooltip displays correctly. Can you help me resolve this?

The section below is where I'm setting the properties for the chart:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of codeblocks ... read: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)